# Creating pdfs from predefined templates in java

Tags: java, html, pdf-generation

My Spring application needs to create different types of PDF documents like invoices and certificates each having dynamic data .I would like to have some predefined templates(html/text file) from which I can generate the full PDF content. The predefined template holds the full content of the PDF document including the font size, alignments of each section etc and also have key values that need to be replaced with actual values form database. I know it is easy to create PDFs from html. Is anyone having any idea on how to accept an html template as input in a java program and then hook in the keys defined in it with actual values and finally creating the PDFs?

Comment: Have you considered generating XML or JSON data, and from that HTML and PDF?

Comment: @MauricePerry Could you please send me some links such that I can refer to? Thanks.

Comment: if you generate XML documents with your data, you can use an XSLT template to generate HTML, and an XSLT-FO template to generate a PDF: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: @MauricePerry Thanks. I will have a look.

Comment: This is another place you might want to look at: [converting HTML to PDF](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks. I had a look through the above link. But I am struggling to get the license key. Is the license key once downloaded used for ever? or has it got an expiry? I downloaded the key from (https://repo.itextsupport.com/list/releases/com/itextpdf/itext-licensekey/)

Comment: iText 7 and pdfHTML also work without a license key, however, that implies that you are using iText for free under the AGPL. If you can't comply with the rules of the AGPL (e.g. because you want to use the software in a closed source context), then you need to purchase a commercial license and you'll obtain a license key.

Comment: The main reason why the license key is mentioned in the examples, is that some people think that open source software is *for free*. They confuse free software with freeware. I never understood such developers, because the rules are really simple. However, some developers just download stuff without ever thinking about the rules (and that's a pity).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the update. We decided to use iText under the AGPL.

Comment: Is anyone having experience in using iText under AGPL?

Comment: Please read the guidelines: [How do I make sure my software complies with AGPL: How can I use iText for free?](https://itextpdf.com/blog/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free) This video is also a great help: [The Impact of Leveraging Open Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwrSMj-Prfw) Some people try to open source only a minimal part of their code, but the AGPL requires you to open source a substantial part of your project. There's also https://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/ianal-what-developers-should-know-about-ip-and-legal

Comment: You're creating a templating tool that can produce invoices and certificates. If you go for the AGPL, you need to make that an open source project and publish *all your code for free* on GitHub. That might make it very hard for you to make any money with your project. As an alternative, you could choose to be part of the [iText developer platform](https://itextpdf.com/itext-developer-platform). In that case, you can get paid for using iText, instead of having to pay. The choice is up to you. Just make sure you do it right, because the AGPL has been enforced in court before (see slide deck).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks. I had already gone through the link [https://itextpdf.com/blog/how-do-i-make-sure-my-software-complies-agpl-how-can-i-use-itext-free] We decided to make the entire source code that generates PDF publicly available.

Comment: Great! Let me known where you publish it so that we can promote it.